# how to show the successful message in bootstrap successful alert after inserting the data successfully

Tags: php, alert, bootbox

How to show alert messages in green for some moment or have a close button at right side after inserting into database.

```
    <?php
include('../session.php');
$from="$session_id";
$to=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["to"]);
$subject=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ssubject"]);
$message=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["smessage"]);
if($from==$to){
    echo "Message could not be sent";
    die();
}
if($from>1 && $to>1){
    echo "Message could not be sent";
    die();
}



//echo $to.$message;
//validate before insert
if(strlen($subject)>50){
    echo "Subject was too long";
    die();
}
if(strlen($message)>150){
    echo "Message was too long";
    die();
}
include('../dbsource.php');
$mysqli=connect();

if(insert($mysqli,$from,$to,$subject,$message)>0)

{
   // echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
       // "alert('Message was successfully sent');".
        //"</script>";
   $result='successfully sent message';


    }
else
{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "alert('there was error sending message.. please try it later');".
        "</script>";

}
?>


<?php
function insert($mysqli,$from,$to,$subject,$message){   
    $mdate=date('Y-m-d');
    $mtime=date('H:i:s');   
    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (mfrom,mto,subject,message,mdate,mtime)".
        "VALUES ('$from','$to','$subject','$message','$mdate','$mtime')";
    if($mysqli->query($query)>0)
        return($mysqli->insert_id);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

and the php page consist the code as:

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong><? $result ?>
</div>
```

how to show the successful message in bootstrap alert box?

Comment: "waiting for answer" .......

Comment: Assuming you're using Bootstrap _and_ Bootbox (which is built on top of, and therefore requires, Bootstrap): `bootbox.alert('Your message here')`.

Answer (score 0):

i know this answer is very late , but i think maybe someone like me want an answer

i have 2 function to process (inserting in database)

```
<?php
$nameErr = "";
$familyErr = "";
$codeErr = "";
$passErr = "";
function create_student($name, $family, $code, $pass)
{
    global $conn, $tbl_student;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_student (students_code, students_pass, students_name, students_family) VALUES (? ,? ,?,?)";
    $create_student = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $create_student->bindParam(1, $code);
    $create_student->bindParam(2, $pass);
    $create_student->bindParam(3, $name);
    $create_student->bindParam(4, $family);
    $create_student->execute();
    $student=$name." ".$family;
    if($create_student->rowCount()>=1){
        $result_create_student=['1',$student];
    }
    else
    {
        $result_create_student=['0',"error in inserting"];
    }
    return $result_create_student;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['submit-create-student']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {
    if (empty($_POST["student-name"])) {
        $nameErr = "you must insert name.";
    } else {
        $name = sanitize_func($_POST["student-name"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["student-family"])) {
        $familyErr = "you must insert family.";
    } else {
        $family = sanitize_func($_POST["student-family"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["student-code"])) {
        $codeErr = "you must insert code.";
    } else {
        $code = sanitize_func($_POST["student-code"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["student-pass"])) {
        $passErr = "you must insert pass.";
    } else {
        $pass = sanitize_func($_POST["student-pass"]);
    }
    if (($nameErr == "") && ($familyErr == "") && ($codeErr == "") && ($passErr == "")) {
        $result_create_student=create_student($name, $family, $code,$pass);
    }
}
?>
```

and the part we want show result in my code i do like this

```
<div class="px-2 text-right schms-font-size-12 mb-1">
                                            <?php if (isset($result_create_student) && $result_create_student != "") : ?>
                                                <?php if ($result_create_student[0] == '1'): ?>
                                                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible text-right">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;
                                                        </button>
                                                        <strong class="pl-1">success!</strong>
                                                        one student with name
                                                        <span  class="text-justify"><?php echo $result_create_student[1]; ?></span>
                                                       inserting in databse.
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php elseif ($result_create_student[0] == '0'): ?>
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible text-right">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;
                                                        </button>
                                                        <strong class="pl-1">error!</strong>
                                                        <span  class="text-justify"><?php echo $result_create_student[1]; ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
```

i hope it's useful